# How many ways are there to put 'n' figures on a chess board?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to put n figures on an n x n chess board, if in at least one vertical row there are no figures?
note: the figures are indistinguishable from each other

Comment: Consider the opposite event: **All vertical rows have a figure**.  Can you count this opposite situation?  Can you count the situation where we don't care about rows?

Comment: is it $\binom{(n-1)*n}{n}$ ? because now we basically have the same situation as in an (n-1)*n chessboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Count the number of ways to arrange the figures if each vertical row has a figure. Then subtract this from the total ways to arrange the figures, disregarding the rows/columns present.